# Constraint on fixed distance between 2 objects not respected

Tags: game-engine, physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

[Blender 2.76b]

Hello, I'm trying to physically simulate a robot structure in BGE. Right now, I'm only trying to connect two servos together. The problem is, the rigid body constraint(generic 6dof) that is supposed to fix the upper servo to the frame does not seem to be working correctly, as proved by this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZszYQha9-U)

Scalings are applied, the masses are 720 for the servo and 10 for the frame. I noticed setting more similar masses alleviates the problem but 1) it does not disappear completely, 2) I want the simulation to be realistic NOT feel realistic, so playing with the masses is out of question.

The physics sub steps are set to 5, the maximum allowed by blender's interface. What I don't understand is that in blender render, the same configuration behaves normally (I don't want to switch to it because blender game engine gives me some useful methods I want to use)

The file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_iCEk8P-TViODNTcXgzUFl4aGc/view?usp=sharing)